# How to specify discriminator value for the parent table using single table inheritance?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have several entities using single table inheritance:

```js
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'documentType' } })
export class Document {
    ...
    @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: DocumentType })
    documentType: DocumentType;
    ....
}
```

```js
@ChildEntity(DocumentType.TRAINING_DOCUMENT)
export class TrainingDocument extends Document { ... }
```

```js
@ChildEntity(DocumentType.GENERATED_RECORD)
export class GeneratedRecord extends Document { ... }
```

I also have an enum for `DocumentType`

```js
export enum DocumentType {
    DOCUMENT = 'DOCUMENT',
    TRAINING_DOCUMENT = 'TRAINING_DOCUMENT',
    GENERATED_RECORD = 'GENERATED_RECORD'
}
```

I can specify the discriminator value for the child entities (TrainingDocument, and GeneratedRecord), but I can't see a way to specify it for the parent (Document) class.

When I go to insert into my document repo I get the following error:

```
QueryFailedError: invalid input value for enum document_documenttype_enum: "Document"
```

I have looked at the docs and I can't see any way to specify the discriminator value in the decorators.

I have also tried manually setting the `documentType` field when I create the entity, but it seems that TypeORM overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a SingleTable you cant instance the parent entity for save it in the DB, you need to use any of the child entites so you can specify the discriminator value as you have done it. Create a child entity normalDocument and specified de discriminator value as DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT so you can get what you are looking for.